# Parse JSON with swiftyJSON and more

Tags: json, swift

Hi I've tried to parse my JSON but I couldn't get my data from it,
(I used SwiftyJSON)
how can I parse this ugly JSON?

//Mark: parser functions:

```
 private func parseProvincesResult(provincesJSON: JSON, completion: @escaping(_ :ProvincesV2) -> Void) {
    
 
    print(provincesJSON)
    
    let errorCode: Int = provincesJSON["ErrorCode"].intValue
    let errorDescriptions: String = provincesJSON["ErrorString"].stringValue
    let newMacKey: String = provincesJSON["NewMacKey"].stringValue
    let newPinKey: String = provincesJSON["NewPinKey"].stringValue
    let version: Int = provincesJSON["Ver"].intValue
    var provinceList: [ProvinceListResult] = []
    
    for i in provincesJSON["ProvinceListResult"].arrayValue {
        
        let id: Int = i["Id"].intValue
        let name: String = i["Name"].stringValue
        
        let proList =  ProvinceListResult(id: id, name: name)
        provinceList.append(proList)

        }
        
        let model = ProvincesV2(errorCode: errorCode, errorDescriptions: errorDescriptions, newMacKey: newMacKey, newPinKey: newPinKey, version: version, provinceList: provinceList)
        completion(model)
    }
```

and my JSON is:

```
 {"ErrorCode":"8",
"ErrorString":"عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد.",
"NewMacKey":"vph+eLFgxa6LVq90QfsNUA==",
"NewPinKey":"evJiM9W6S9RWEClR6csxEQ==",
"Ver":201,
"ProvinceListResult":[{"Id":1,"Name":"آذربايجان شرقي"},
{"Id":2,"Name":"آذربايجان غربي"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"اردبيل"},
{"Id":4,"Name":"اصفهان"},
{"Id":5,"Name":"البرز"},
{"Id":6,"Name":"ايلام"},
{"Id":7,"Name":"بوشهر"},
{"Id":8,"Name":"تهران"},
{"Id":9,"Name":"چهارمحال و بختياري"},
{"Id":10,"Name":"خراسان جنوبي"},{"Id":11,"Name":"خراسان رضوي"},{"Id":12,"Name":"خراسان شمالي"},{"Id":13,"Name":"خوزستان"},{"Id":14,"Name":"زنجان"},{"Id":15,"Name":"سمنان"},{"Id":16,"Name":"سيستان و بلوچستان"},{"Id":17,"Name":"فارس"},{"Id":18,"Name":"قزوين"},{"Id":19,"Name":"قم"},{"Id":20,"Name":"کردستان"},{"Id":21,"Name":"کرمان"},{"Id":22,"Name":"کرمانشاه"},{"Id":23,"Name":"کهکيلويه و بويراحمد"},{"Id":24,"Name":"گلستان"},{"Id":25,"Name":"گيلان"},{"Id":26,"Name":"لرستان"},{"Id":27,"Name":"مازندران"},{"Id":28,"Name":"مرکزي"},{"Id":29,"Name":"هرمزگان"},{"Id":30,"Name":"همدان"},{"Id":31,"Name":"يزد"},{"Id":44,"Name":"کیش"}]}
```

how can I parse It?
tnx

Comment: You should read up on `Codable`, it’s swift built in functionality for encoding and decoding json and it’s very good at it.

Comment: Use this for export your data to SwiftyJson or any other : https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Codable, you could do this:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let errorCode, errorString, newMACKey, newPinKey: String
    let ver: Int
    let provinceListResult: [ProvinceListResult]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case errorCode = "ErrorCode"
        case errorString = "ErrorString"
        case newMACKey = "NewMacKey"
        case newPinKey = "NewPinKey"
        case ver = "Ver"
        case provinceListResult = "ProvinceListResult"
    }
}

// MARK: - ProvinceListResult
struct ProvinceListResult: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

(generated by https://app.quicktype.io)

And getting a value out might look like:

```
let welcome = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
            print(welcome?.provinceListResult[1])
print(welcome?.provinceListResult[1])
```

If your original data is in `String` form, it can be converted to `Data` by doing this:

```
myStringJSON.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Answer (score 0):

create two models for parse JSON

first for the province:

```
public struct ProvinceModel {
    
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    
    init(json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["Id"].int
        self.name = json["Name"].string
    }
}
```

with a constructor, you can parse JSON and set data to variables.

and second model:

```
public struct MyJSONModel {
    
    var errorString: String?
    var newMacKey: String?
    var newPinKey: String?
    var Ver: Int?
    var Provinces: [ProvinceModel]?
    
    init(json: JSON) {
        
        // simple parse
        self.errorString = json["ErrorCode"].string
        self.newMacKey = json["NewMacKey"].string
        self.newPinKey = json["NewPinKey"].string
        self.Ver = json["Ver"].int
        
        // array
        self.Provinces = [] // empty array
        if let jsonArray = json["ProvinceListResult"].array {
            
            for json in jsonArray {
                let ProvinceObject = ProvinceModel.init(json: json)
                self.Provinces?.append(ProvinceObject)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for parse province items in the array, you must create a loop and create an object then set in variables

I prefer to use a constructor for parse JSON instead of a custom function.